# PHP form automatically refreshes whenever data is entered

Tags: php, forms, include, page-refresh

I'm building my first PHP website (attempting to, anyway!), and I'm trying to create a contact form whose contents are submitted to me via email. I've got the email part down, but I'm having trouble getting the form ("contact.php") to accept data. It automatically refreshes as soon as I type a character in any field. Here's the relevant code:

```
<div class="contactform">
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact-receiver.php">

<fieldset><legend><strong>Required Information</strong></legend>

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="35" maxlength="30"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="35" maxlength="30"/>
Email: <input type="text" name="emailAddress" size="60" maxlength="55"/>

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

</form>
</div>
```

This works fine when tested independent from the rest of the site. However, here's the context:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

switch($id)
{
    case 'main':
    include 'storeinfo.php';
    break;
    case 'shop':
    include 'inventory.php';
    break;
    case 'cart':
    include 'cart.php';
    break;
    case 'contact':
    include 'contact.php';
    break;
    default:
    include 'error.php';
}
?>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

"contact.php" works fine when displayed as a separate page, but won't accept any input when accessed as an include file. If I try to enter data in any of the fields, the page immediately refreshes after I type the first character, and the data is lost.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

**EDIT**

Disabling Javascript didn't work. I cleared my cache and restarted my browser (Firefox) just to be sure. While I'm working on that voodoo priest, here's the page source for index.php?id=contact:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Main</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div>

<p><img src='headerimg.png' class='header'/></p><a href='index.php?id=main'>
<img src='mainbutton.png' class='nav1'</a><a href='index.php?id=shop'>
<img src='shopbutton.png' class='nav2'</a><a href='index.php?id=cart'>
<img src='cartbutton.png' class='nav2'</a><a href='index.php?id=contact'>
<img src='contactbutton.png' class='nav2'</a>

</div>

<div class="contactform">

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact-receiver.php">

<fieldset><legend><strong>Required Information</strong></legend>

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="35" maxlength="30"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="35" maxlength="30"/>
Email: <input type="text" name="emailAddress" size="60" maxlength="55"/>

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

</form>

</div>  
<div id = "footer">

<p>&copy;2012</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably related to your `header.php` or `footer.php`, like some javascript that doing some `form` handling, it's hard to say what's wrong since the code you currently provided doesn't have described issue...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a Javascript-related problem.

Check and make sure you're not including any scripts which try to autocomplete, as being misconfigured might cause it to send a request upon key up which would cause the behavior you're mentioning.

An easy way to test this is to disable JavaScript in your browser and see if the issue continues.  If it does, it means you have ghosts in your computer and should see a voodoo priest.  If the issue doesn't persist, it means it's an issue with some JavaScript on your site.

Posting some contents of header.php will help, as well.  OR, you could simply post the complete HTML page source once - that is, visit your `index.php?id=contact` page, hit view source, and show that here.